# Right Button won't show in custom Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My app is a tab bar app with many navigation controllers.
I want these navigation controllers to handle login/logout actions with a custom right bar button. So I've set up my tab bar in AppDelegate this way :

```
MyFirstViewController *firstViewController = [[MyFirstViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *firstNavigationController = [[CustomNavigationController alloc]
                                               initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

MySecondViewController *secondViewController = [[MySecondViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *secondNavigationController = [[CustomNavigationController alloc]
                                               secondViewController]
                                               initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];

....

[tabBarController setViewControllers:@[firstNavigationController, secondNavigationController]];
```

Then `CustomNavigationController` :

```
@implementation ConnectionNavigationController

- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    [self displayConnectionButton];
}

- (void) displayConnectionButton
{
    UIImage *portraitImage, *landscapeImage;
    portraitImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"conn.png"];
    landscapeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"connLandscape.png"];

    UIBarButtonItem *connButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithImage:[portraitImage
                                                  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
                                   landscapeImagePhone:[landscapeImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showConnectionPopup)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = connButton;
}

@end
```

I tried with `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillAppear` but nothing works, I can't get this button to show in the navigation bar. I also tried to add `reloadInputViews` or `setNeedsDisplay`. What should I do?

Thanks for your help

**Edit : interface of CustomNavigationController**

```
@interface ConnectionNavigationController : UINavigationController

- (void) displayConnectionButton;

@end
```

Comment: Can you add the `@interface` of `ConnectionNavigationController` please?

Comment: @lucianomarisi I did it, you will see there is not a lot in it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you should add the `displayConnectionButton` method to the relevant `UIViewController` subclass and not to your `UINavigationController` subclass as this only contains the stack of view controllers.

E.g.

```
@implementation MyFirstViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    [self displayConnectionButton];
}

- (void) displayConnectionButton
{
    UIImage *portraitImage, *landscapeImage;
    portraitImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"conn.png"];
    landscapeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"connLandscape.png"];

    UIBarButtonItem *connButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithImage:[portraitImage
                                                  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
                                   landscapeImagePhone:[landscapeImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showConnectionPopup)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = connButton;
}

@end
```

As a note if you put a breakpoint on your `displayConnectionButton` in your `CustomNavigationController` and `po self.viewControllers` I think you will get an empty array (i.e. no view controllers)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I did first, but if I do so I'll have to add the same code in every controller of my app, right?

Comment: You could have a `BaseViewController` class with this code and subclass your `MyFirstViewController` and `MySecondViewController` from that.

Comment: This is correct.  UINavigationBar (inside your UINavigationController) manages a stack of UINavigationItems which it gets from all of your UIViewControllers.  Read the UIViewController doc entry for navigationItem for more information.